# Login infinte loop on ubntu and tty terminal

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, login-screen

I got stuck in infinte login loop in Ubuntu. When i try to login from tty, it just ask me to login again.

The text appear momentarily with last line 'system reboot required'.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

What it says you should do: **Reboot and try again.**

Comment: Funny. Ofcourse i did that and no avail.

Comment: Try logging in as root and see if that works.. or any other account to see if its an account related problem.

Comment: Read [answer] before answering. If you think that the OP has not performed a test, leave a comment.